# Using a php variable in concatenated string in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, concatenation

I'm working on a project where the opening page is .php.  It allows users to select a map file they want to view.  That page sends the variable to another page that has javascript on it.  I'm not a js programmer, so I'm struggling here.  The problem is that I need to apply that variable from the php page to a concatenated string in the js.  Here's what I have...

```
<script>
<?php 
  $filename = $_GET["filename"];
  $fileTrimed = str_replace(".mxd", "", $filename);
?> 
var trimmed = (<?php $fileTrimed ?>)
var firstURL = "http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/";
var secondURL = "/MapServer";
var finalURL = firstURL + trimmed + secondURL;
```

I have also tried it as...

```
?>
var firstURL = "http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/";
var secondURL = "/MapServer";
var finalURL = firstURL + $fileTrimed + secondURL;
```

I appreciate any help y'all can offer.

Comment: var trimmed = (<?php echo $fileTrimed ?>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
 var finalURL = firstURL + "<?php echo $fileTrimed; ?>" + secondURL;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing a single echo

this code :

```
var trimmed = (<?php $fileTrimed ?>)
```

Should look like :

```
var trimmed = (<?php echo $fileTrimed; ?>)
```

Comment: Raikeru, it appears everyone agrees with you.  However, it does not seem to work.  I even moved the code to a test page to isolate it.  I commented out the "trimmed" variable and was able to get the other variables to print.  I then only uncommented the var trimmed = (<?php echo $fileTrimed ?>) line and tried to print trimmed immediately after that line.  The page remained blank.  Is there another component I could be missing, please?

Comment: Ah, I have the answer thanks to another friend.  For the record, you cannot have the ().  Instead of (<?php echo $fileTrimed ?>),it should be "<?php echo $fileTrimed ?>" just like @Sahil Mittal posted below.  Thank you for taking the time to respond, both of you.